# When is the Apple MDM Push Notification Token Generated?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I know that in order to receive a push notification, an iOS app must register with the APN service, where it will receive this token, which it will then forward to the server that needs to send push notifications to the app.

But, when it comes to MDM push notifications, we don't have an app running on the device. Therefore, when the device is about to enroll with the MDM server, it send the server its token. My question is, where / how or at which point does it receive this token ?

I am trying to send an MDM push notification, but I keep receiving an error from the APN service about the token being invalid.

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: I am not referring to the magic token, but rather the push token.

Answer (score 0):

During the initial enrollment back-and-forth the device will send an XML string one of whom's attributes will be `PushMagic`. You need to save this value in your MDM database and use it whenever you want to "ping" the managed device asking it to check-in with the MDM server.

Comment: thank you for the response.. but I am not referring to the magic token. I am referring to the push token that the device sends along with the magic token. Do you have an idea on that ?

Comment: There are two other tokens that can be sent along with `PushMagic`. They are `Token` and `UnlockToken`. I am guessing you mean `Token` which is sent when asking the managed device to check in; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047002/how-to-send-an-apple-mdm-push-notification-with-plain-php/13049946#13049946

Comment: Yes is `Token` that I am referring to. `Token` will be what the APNs uses to forward the push notification to my device right ? Do I need to add the `UnlockToken` to this push notification as well ? I don't see that you have done that in the link you've posted above.

Comment: If one of the access rights permitted your MDM service is device passcode clear, then the `UnlockToken` will be sent. If clearing passcodes is something you want to do, then you should save it. Otherwise, you can safely ignore `UnlockToken`.